# Default localhost can't be accessed after installing virtual hosts on WAMP

Tags: wordpress, apache, localhost, wamp, vhosts

I'll really appreciate a little help with a problem I have been struggling with all day long...  I installed WordPress locally using WAMP and everything worked fine. I created a folder inside  C:/wamp/www an named it wordpress. 
I was able to access localhost only by typing localhost on the browser's URL and I accessed the site typing localhost/wordpress/ BUT when I decided to install another wordpress website I faced a problem.  I created a second folder inside www, named it joanaweb and followed the steps of this tutorial: http://www.marolinedesign.com/tutorials/how-to-install-more-than-one-wordpress-site-on-your-local-wamp-server/ PLUS I removed the # before Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf located on httpd.conf which  wasn't mentioned in the tutorial.
After this the first website was accessed as before while the second by typing joanaweb....BUT i  couldn't access localhost anymore :( I got just a 403 Error. In this website http://www.apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php  at the end of the article I found a solution but it isn't working for me :/ They suggested using:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot C:\Apache\htdocs
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Since I have htdocs located on another folder I used this code on httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/htdocs/"
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
ErrorLog "logs/localhost.log"
CustomLog "logs/localhost.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/joanaweb"
ServerName joanaweb
ServerAlias joanaweb
ErrorLog "logs/joanaweb.log"
CustomLog "logs/joanaweb.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong??

Also this is all the code inside my hosts file(after the comments):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1        localhost
127.0.0.1        localhost
127.0.0.1        localhost localhost
127.0.0.1        localhost wordpress
127.0.0.1        localhost joanaweb
127.0.0.1        localhost lifestylepro
127.0.0.1        localhost xxxxxTranslations
```

And this is the code inside httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
        </IfDefine>
        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/wordpress"
    ServerName wordpress
    ServerAlias wordpress
       <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/wordpress">
        AllowOverride All
        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
        </IfDefine>
        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/wordpress.log"
    CustomLog "logs/wordpress.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/joanaweb"
    ServerName joanaweb
    ServerAlias joanaweb
       <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/joanaweb">
        AllowOverride All
        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
        </IfDefine>
        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/joanaweb.log"
    CustomLog "logs/joanaweb.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/lifestylepro"
    ServerName lifestylepro
    ServerAlias lifestylepro
       <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/lifestylepro">
        AllowOverride All
        <IfDefine APACHE24>
             Require local
        </IfDefine>
        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/lifestylepro.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lifestylepro.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/xxxxxTranslations"
    ServerName xxxxxTranslations
    ServerAlias www.xxxxxTranslations
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/xxxxxTranslations">
        AllowOverride All
        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
        </IfDefine>
        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/xxxxxTranslations.log"
    CustomLog "logs/xxxxxTranslations.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you edited your hosts file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`?

Comment: Yes I have added this line of code for the second website...  127.0.0.1       joanaweb

Comment: You should have your name and alias end in a TLD (`.com` or `.dev` or the like).

Comment: I read somewhere they were optional, but maybe that was not correct. Thank you for your answer I'll try it now

Comment: it didn't work :/ I think I'll have to "turn off" the other sites and let only www/wordpress when I'll need to access localhost, anyway thank you :)

Comment: @Aibrean No you dont actually. I makes more sense to use somthing as a TLD like ,dev but its not actually necessary

Answer (score 1):

Ok first get rid of these 2 section of `httpd-vhosts.conf`, these 2 bits are just what Apache release as sample code to get you started and are irrelevant to WAMPServer as they point to locations that are not used by WAMPServer.

So delete these 2 definitions

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And then we come to **your** Virtual Hosts definitions, as you are using Apache v2.4.x I will remove the Apache versions checks and just use Apache 2.4 syntax to make it easier to understand.

```
# Should be the first VHOST definition so that it is the default virtual host
# Also access rights should remain restricted to the local PC and the local network
# So that any random ip address attack will recieve an error code and not gain access
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/wordpress"
    ServerName wordpress
    ServerAlias wordpress
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/wordpress">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/wordpress.log"
    CustomLog "logs/wordpress.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/joanaweb"
    ServerName joanaweb
    ServerAlias joanaweb
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/joanaweb">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/joanaweb.log"
    CustomLog "logs/joanaweb.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/lifestylepro"
    ServerName lifestylepro
    ServerAlias lifestylepro
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/lifestylepro">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/lifestylepro.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lifestylepro.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/xxxxxTranslations"
    ServerName xxxxxTranslations
    ServerAlias www.xxxxxTranslations
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/xxxxxTranslations">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/xxxxxTranslations.log"
    CustomLog "logs/xxxxxTranslations.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now there is the HOSTS file. This needs to include the ip address for both IPC4 i.e. 127.0.0.1
and the ip address for IPV6 i.e. ::1

So change your HOSTS file to this, removing the unnecessary duplication and adding IPV6 references :-

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  wordpress
127.0.0.1  joanaweb
127.0.0.1  lifestylepro
127.0.0.1  xxxxxTranslations

::1  localhost
::1  wordpress
::1  joanaweb
::1  lifestylepro
::1  xxxxxTranslations
```

Now to make sure these are loaded into the dnscache, launch a command window using the "Run as Administrator" option and run these 2 commands.

Alternatively, just reboot, to make these current.

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

Now restart Apache, so these changes are picked up, and try your vhosts.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice. I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work.  I then changed <IfDefine APACHE24> into <IfDefine APACHE249> and then into <IfDefine APACHE2.4.9> but it still didn't work...Another strange thing that happens is that when I access my first site: localhost/wordpress it renders good, but when I access directly wordpress/ it renders with some uncompleted icons, images, etc.

Comment: In addition I don't believe the location of localhost is still /wamp/www . Look what it says in the second article that I have mentioned above: " .... the default http://localhost will no longer work. In many cases, that is unimportant. However, if you're using something like phpMyAdmin, you'll still need it. The solution to that is to create one additional virtual host called "localhost" that points to the original Apache htdocs folder. It might look something like this:"

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot C:\Apache\htdocs
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

Comment: The second article you mention is aimed a people who install Apache manually i.e. **NOT WAMPServer** so it is completely irrelevant. The variable **APACHE24** is defined in `httpd.conf` line `24` so testing for `APACHE2.4.9` is also **Irrelevant** But you know best!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I actually don't know best :/ but that article was the only one I found that mentioned a same problem as what I'm struggling with....Fortunately until now I've not needed to access localhost, but still I hope to find what's wrong with it.

Comment: OK, so, If you installed WAMPServer, everything is installed INSIDE the `\wamp`  folder. The location of the WAMPServer homepage ( what you are calling localhost ) is in `\wamp\www` and is basically one file called `\wamp\www\index.php` **unless you have damaged this folder or deleted the original contents** Also did you add the new joanweb to the `HOSTS` file?

Comment: So I've got this files inside \wamp\www : index.php; testmysql.php; favicon.ico and this folders: wordpress(the first website), joanaweb, lifestylepro and xxxxxTranslations. While inside the hosts file I have added: 127.0.0.1      localhost;  
127.0.0.1        localhost wordpress; 
127.0.0.1        localhost joanaweb; 
127.0.0.1        localhost lifestylepro; 
127.0.0.1        localhost xxxxxxTranslations

Comment: Edit your question and put all the httpd-vhosts.conf file in there. Also post the contents of the file `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: I have one last question, what about the folder **vhosts** which is placed inside \wamp. I opened it and there was only one **empty** file inside it called **none**. Should it be empty?? I'm also thinking of installing wamp 2.5 following this instructions: [link](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606) obviously without overriding wamp 2.4 Maybe after this everything will work fine

Comment: The `wamp\vhosts` folder should be empty. That idea was created in WAMPServer 2.4, but has since been dropped. They just left the folder there in case people had made use of the folder to include VHOST definitions. If you are using the `httpd-vhost.conf` file to create your Virtual Hosts thats the way to go..

Comment: Ok, completely rewritten my answer now I have more information. Hope this sorts it out

Comment: Hi again. Firstly I wanted to thank you for your well explained answer. And secondly I believe I am to blame for the steps I've followed on installing WAMP, cause even this solution didn't work out. Can you please give me an opinion if this actions I took have caused the problem??1. I've clicked on the WAMP Icon--> Apache-->Apache modules and on **rewrite_module** in order to activate it. (Now I noticed that some of the modules have the exclamation mark before them...this isn't good I think)

Comment: 2. To configure PHP, I've opened php.ini and **removed the semicolon** before **error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED** and before **error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log**. I've also edited 2 lines of code like this: **post_max_size = 50M** and **upload_max_filesize = 50M**

Comment: Hi, Ask the question on [the wampserver forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2) and I will offer to do a TeamViewer session with you to get this solved.

Comment: Thank you for your CONTINUOUS help @RiggsFolly. I'll do as you advise asap. Have a wonderful day!!! :)